# Apache ServerName being ignored

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, virtualhost, lamp

Apache seems to ignore the ServerName for a particular virtual host. I have posted the output of apachectl -S:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
81.145.239.71:80       www.actualvirtual.co.uk (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
         port 80 namevhost crmdev.actualvirtual.co.uk (/opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:1)
*:80                   localhost (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf:8)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server crmdev.actualvirtual.co.uk (/opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:7)
         port 443 namevhost crmdev.actualvirtual.co.uk (/opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:7)
         port 443 namevhost localhost (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf:55)
```

As you can see, it's pulling the config files correctly, however it's ignoring the crmdev.actualvirtual.co.uk ServerName directive. The config for the virtual host is here:

```
<VirtualHost 81.145.239.69:80>
    ServerName crmdev.actualvirtual.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd-app.conf has:

```
<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
  <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/suitecrm.sock|fcgi://suitecrm-fpm" timeout=300>
  </Proxy>
</IfDefine>

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs">
  Options +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion >= 2.3>
      Require all granted
  </IfVersion>


  <IfModule php5_module>
     php_value upload_max_filesize 60M
     php_value post_max_size 60M
     php_value memory_limit 256M

  </IfModule>

  <IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
    <IfModule pagespeed_module>
      ModPagespeed off
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
     SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://suitecrm-fpm"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfDefine>

</Directory>
```

Comment: I can't see how it is ignoring the `crmdev.actualvirtual.co.uk` no, because I see 3 vhosts in your output using that name?  You are going to need to actually include your configuration here, and tell us which virtual hosts you are expecting to show up as that name, but isn't.

Comment: how is `/opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:1" VirtualHost directive configured? Show us.